# Creating directory objects in Oracle 11g with relative path

Tags: oracle, file, jdbc, plsql, directory

I'm using JDBC to create a directory object in the database.

i.e create or replace directory "dir" as 'c:\temp';

My question is:

1. I want to pass the path at runtime
2. Or at least specify path relative to current one. I mean : create or replace "dir" as './../tempdir'

Is there a way to do this or is specifying absolute path the only way out.

Comment: Why do you want relative paths? Are you sure you know what they would be relative to? What do you mean by "current path"? Those are file paths on the database server, unaffected by where you run the client from.

Comment: I'm using Oracle capture and replay in my App.By relative path, I mean the generated capture files to be stored in a directory inside the App folder. By, current path I mean my .java file's path in which I'm writing the "create directory" statement

Comment: Oracle does not allow dynamic manipulation of DIRECTORY objects, for very sound reasons.  Get the full skinny by reading my response to another SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147756/make-directory-part-dynamic-in-call-to-bfilename-function-in-oracle-10g/8149548#8149548

Answer (score 2):

From [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5007.htm):

> **path_name** Specify the *full path name* of the operating system directory
>   of the server where the files are located.

I think this is because there is no such thing as "current directory". (You are in database, not in command line :) )

You can post a question with your problem and you'll get help from community.

Comment: Note that you could use a relative path, relative to the absolute path specified by the `DIRECTORY`. That's the case when you use a `BFILE` where the `BFILE` locator = `DIRECTORY` + relative path.

Comment: have you tried that? [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions011.htm#i76871) says that should be Directory + filename